# Sorting array algorithm error

Tags: c

Hi I wrote this sorting algorithm and I'm not sure why I'm getting the following error: "member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union"

```
void sort(float avg_dist, cg[]){

    int i,j,t;

    for(i=1; i<=cg[i]-1; i++)
        for(j=1; j<=cg[i]-i; j++)
            if(cg[j-1].avg_dist >= cg[j].avg_dist){
                t = cg[j-1];
                cg[j-1] = cg[j];
                cg[j] = t;

            }

}
```

Comment: What line provoke that error ?

Comment: What type `cg` is? It's an invalid function declaration (well, valid for the compiler, but you don't mean it).

Comment: @EugeneSh.: "valid for the compiler ..."? That is non standard at least.

Comment: @Olaf See blue112 comment. I am assuming the compiler is not complaining about it, otherwise it won't reach the reported line.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Fair enough. I just wonder: if there were only C compiler for C99 upward with all relevant warnings enabled and made errors: would there be more or less questions by beginners, or would just the focus shift?

Answer (score 2):

`cg` is an int array.

You can't access a "member" of an int, as in

```
cg[j-1].avg_dist
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Maybe multiply ?

```
 cg[j-1] * avg_dist
```

Comment: I guess the problem is in the argument list declaration. It lacks type.

Comment: "A variable declared without an explicit type name is assumed to be of type int." as of C89.

Comment: As I said, I believe the OP doesn't mean it.

Comment: Plus one for the insight with the multiplication. Which I stole ;=)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem, but you're (perhaps intentionally) omitting the *type* specifier in your function

`void sort(float avg_dist, cg[]){`

C is defaulting to an `int` array type, which of course, renders `cg[j].avg_dist` syntactically invalid. (In reality you probably want to multiply by `avg_dist`, use `*` rather than the member selection operator `.`).

Comment: I actually intentionally used "." as a member selection operator

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a clear Idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sortArray(int *array, int length){
  int i,j, k, temp;

  for (i = 0 ; i < length-1; i++){
    for (k = 0 ; k < length-i-1; k++){
      if (array[k] > array[k+1]){
        temp = array[k];
        array[k]   = array[k+1];
        array[k+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

    printf("The result:\n");

  for ( j = 0 ; j < length ; j++ ){
    printf("%d  ", array[j]);
  }
}

int main(void){
    int array[] = {1,4,2,-1,2,3,4,1,3,-1};
    int length = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];

    sortArray(array, length);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> The result:
> -1  -1  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4
> ```